# How can a person's ability to contribute to a Merit based society be measured?

Tags: worldbuilding-process

I've been working on a book about a Merit based society where Emotional Quotient (EQ) testing and Intelligence Quotient (IQ) testing are used to determine how much a person can be expected to contribute to the society.

What I'm struggling with is the question of fairness. Is it fair that a highly intelligent person should be required to perform a higher-level job (ie: rocket scientist) to be considered as productive as a person with a low EQ/IQ who may be a street sweeper?

Comment: This reminds me of a Twilight Zone episode where a priest is sentenced to death because he is not helping society according to the judges.

Comment: IQ and EQ are at best _promises_. A meritocracy would of course look not so much at what a person promises but rather at what a person actually _achieves_: contribute to the society's budget or development, write books (which sell or are lauded by critics), employ people, educate children, make discoveries and inventions (which are applied), catch criminals etc.

Comment: I suggest you do some research go back to the beginning. Read Michael Young's *The Rise of Meritocracy 1870-2033: An Essay on Education and Equality* (1958). Why? Michael Young coined the term "meritocracy". The book argues against a society where IQ determines education, social and economic status. But told from the perspective from the society's beneficiary in 2033, but with the hint this will soon be overthrown. It's part-fiction, part-treatise.

Comment: correlated question if you try and force them do they perform worse on average than if you don't. basically is their any actual benefit to forcing in the first place.

Comment: I hope the comments on this question and the answers help you shape your book!  As you can see, it's quite the contentious topic.  On one hand, that means you're guaranteed to have someone disagree with you.  On the other hand, you're free to explore pretty much every self-consistent solution out there, and nobody can tell you otherwise!

Comment: I agree that this is primarily opinion based.

Answer (score 4):

A merit-based society that treats IQ tests as anything more than a "nice to know" thing is kind of an oxymoron. Specially if your society tries to measure "innate" intelligence with them.

But, to your question: **No it isn't.** Mostly because the assumption that higher intelligence -> more productivity isn't necessarily true. There is a *lot* of factors that affect productivity and for most jobs intelligence is far from being the most important.

Also there's the issue of placing some jobs higher than others. Using your example: Street sweepers are *more important* than rocket scientists, as much as it can surprise or shock you.

Comment: Finding a good way to measure merit has been a goal of society for a long time, and we still don't have a good answer. So far the mest we have managed is review boards and elections, both of which are full of bias but better than anything else we have tried. Predicting merit is like trying to predict the weather several years ahead of time, there are just too many variable for it to be possible.

Answer (score 4):

I often say "fair is a four letter word, and an 'f' word, and should be used similarly to other expletives in this category."  I guarantee you that if you talk to two people, you will find at *least* 3 definitions of "fair" on any topic if you're willing to ask hard enough questions.

That being said, what you describe is the fundamental basis of a meritocracy, which is a common subject for utilitarian philosophy.  There are generally two camps on this topic.  One camp believes finding such a metric is extremely difficult, and IQ/EQ is certainly the wrong metric.  The other camp believes finding such a metric is impossible, for any attempt will surely contradict its own moral code.

As an alternative to trying to find the "correct" metric, a topic which has eluded philosophers for millennia (literally), consider writing a book that explores the flaws of using IQ/EQ as a metric.  Such a world may have a great many desirable characteristics, but may have one or two tiny flaws which form a major source of Man vs. World conflict in your story.

This process would be similar to what Asimov did with his three laws of robotics.  He spent a great deal of time exploring corner cases for which his three laws were not ideal.

Comment: Well, to find the best approximation to a common denominator definiton of "merit", what's wrong with good old money?  If someone makes something that some people worth having, or does a job worth doing, those people will give the person money in order to have the thing.  Then logically those who benefit the most people the greatest amount wind up with the most money·  (Of course we have to leave inherited money out of the equation...)

Comment: Guess I'm in the third camp of believing finding such metric is extremely improbable if not effectively impossible & IQ/EQ is wrong. Of course, my reasoning might be without merit.

Comment: @a4android Personally, my issue would be that I've never seen a EQ score worth sneezing at.  Every time we turn anything emotional into numbers, we seem to get it wrong.  I mean, Netflix ranks their movies in a huge number of dimensions (148, if memory serves), so one can expect categorizing humans to be even harder!

Comment: @jamesqf " what's wrong with good old money?" Basically everything. There is effectively no connection between what we pay and what their social value is. All the CEOs could vanish off the face of Earth and our lives will be unaffected. If the garbage collectors vanished, we'd soon be up our armpits in -- well, you know. I've seen people do great work for next to no money & others who were paid in bucket loads do garbage. Merit & money, nothing in common.

Comment: @a4android Actually, there is a connection between what we pay and what their social value is.   It's just a complicated enough relationship to be tricky to see.  The key to money is it is fungible and durable.  Any social value which is fungible and durable is easily captured in money.  The interesting bit of social value is that which is not fungible -- things like good favor with an individual.  (And don't underestimate the effect of CEOs.  You'd be surprised at how much revolves around them)

Comment: There is a connection between payment & social status. By social value I meant their value to society. Doesn't matter how much revolves around CEOs, they will be replaced almost immediately & the world will go on as before. There's a veritable army always waiting in the wings to step into their shoes. Not all social value is fungible and durable otherwise money would capture it well. There are social factors so valuable we cannot afford to pay for them.

Comment: @jamesqf Money is a great measure of how good you are at extracting value from society, it's a terrible measure of how much value you create for society. Example Norman Borlaug saved several billion lives and changed the social structure of several nations, and never made more than a middle class income becasue the money was worth less than the work to him. This is often true of the most valuable members of society.

Comment: @a4android: The problem here is that you are confusing "social value" with your personal tastes.  And, I admit, to a certain extent mine: I see no reason why professional athletes or rap "artists" should be paid large amounts of money, but many people obviously think their activities are worth paying for.  Which of course is the fundamental problem of meritocracy: who gets to define merit?

Comment: @John: There's a good example of the subjectivity of merit.  Borlag might equally be praised for the "Green Revolution", or damned for his contributions to overpopulation and environmental unsustainability.  Who decides?  Or to pick another figure, Margaret Sanger is equally praised and damned by people who have different opinions on birth control.

Comment: @jamesqf No I'm not confusing "social value", though "societal value" is a better term, & my personal taste. My playful examples may have misled. I think we don't know to determine merit or societal value. IQ isn't good. High EQs can be utter bastards. Money doesn't help. It only reveals our desires, power relations & status worship. I agree with you: what is merit? Borlaug & Sanger had great societal impact & didn't paid for it. They did both good & ill with their work. There is no magic bullet for the best way to run societies.

Answer (score 0):

1) EQ/IQ - instead of usual hostile rant against IQ I'd mention a few more issues. Like plenty of minor health and mental problems, that would actually would not let such person to reach their potential. (mild depression is actually not so easy to distinguish from slacking) Or family obligation. Or other did not have right teachers at school. Or it seems that for some jobs good looks is highly beneficial. There are plenty of such stuff that would ask for some adjustment.

Anyway... some guys with Asperger (yeah, I know, now called on autistic spectrum) could have abysmally low EQ and actually be quite good programmers (or rocket scientist).

2) Fairness? All such choices are quite arbitrary. Actually I do not see often people who complain, that successful people generally pay higher taxes from their higher earnings. The problem here is that instead of assessing what they have earned you put their obligation what they are expected to achieve.

What matter is not whether its fair for me (or you), but whether it is feasible society which would perceive that as legit. If yes, then its "fair" for the practical purposes.

Comment: Re "what they are expected to achieve", I could certainly make a lot more money, which would probably translate to societal merit, if I had just stayed in Silicon Valley and worked 60-80 hour weeks for a couple more decades.  By what definition would that be "fair" to me?